# Openfire Error: "...rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor..."

Tags: openfire

I Just installed Openfire 3.9.3 (Ubuntu 12.04), and it works great in Pidgin, but when trying to log in via the Candy client, it fails and firebug returns the following:

> 500 Task
>   org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSessionManager$HttpPacketSender@58b901
>   rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@8aeebf[Terminated, pool size =
>   0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

The only attempt at a solution I could find is at:

[openfire error when try to connect via http-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440897/openfire-error-when-try-to-connect-via-http-bind)

I logged into hxxp://127.0.0.1:9090/server-properties.jsp , but there were no xmpp.httpbind.worker.threads or xmpp.client.processing properties listed. So I added both and assigned each a value of 16. Then restarted the openfire service. But there was absolutely no change.

openfire warning log:

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSessionManager$HttpPacketSender@3ea82c
>   rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@8aeebf[Terminated, pool size =
>   0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

Any suggestions please?

Comment: This makes me cry. No one has any idea what this error means?